# Getting callback url for logic app in ARM

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps

I'm deploying an ARM template, which includes:
azure functions + logic apps.

Following [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/logic-apps/logic-apps-scenario-function-sb-trigger.md) i've created a simple flow:
one of method from azure functions calls logic app. Let's name the method as "A". The logic app as "B":

A calls B.

The logic app (B) contains "callback URL". Method (A) needs to have a callback url to the logic app (B). I need to set up this variable by "copy" this value:

[image]

And in my azure app function I need to set this value as application setting.

Right now, my ARM looks (more and less) like that:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    //(...)
  },
  "variables": {
    //(...)
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      //(...)
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      //(...)
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "name": "[variables('functionAppName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "kind": "functionapp",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]"
      ],
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "name": "web",
          "type": "sourcecontrols",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('functionAppName'))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "RepoUrl": "[parameters('repoURL')]",
            "branch": "[variables('branch')]",
            "IsManualIntegration": true
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('appServicePlanName'))]",
        "siteConfig": {
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('storageAccountName'), ';AccountKey=', listKeys(variables('storageAccountid'),'2015-05-01-preview').key1)]"
            },
            //next my app settings
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('logicAppName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', variables('servicebusConnectionName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/sourcecontrols', variables('functionAppName'), 'web')]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "order-create"
      },
      "properties": {
        "definition": {
          "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
          "actions": {
            //(...)
          },
          "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
              "defaultValue": {},
              "type": "Object"
            }
          },
          "triggers": {
            "manual": {
              "type": "Request",
              "kind": "Http",
              "inputs": {
                "schema": {}
              }
            }
          },
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "outputs": {}
        },
        "parameters": {
          "$connections": {
            "value": {
              "servicebus": {
                "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', resourceGroup().location, '/managedApis/', 'servicebus')]",
                "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', variables('servicebusConnectionName'))]",
                "connectionName": "[variables('servicebusConnectionName')]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "MICROSOFT.WEB/CONNECTIONS",
      "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
      "name": "[variables('servicebusConnectionName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "api": {
          "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', resourceGroup().location, '/managedApis/', 'servicebus')]"
        },
        "displayName": "[parameters('servicebus_1_Connection_DisplayName')]",
        "parameterValues": {
          "connectionString": "[parameters('servicebus_1_connectionString')]"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

My questions are:

1. It's possible to enforce logic app "callbackUrl" during deployment?
2. It's possible to get the 'logic app' callback URL after deploying the logic app and set the "app settings" in azure functions?
3. If not - do I need to write a powershell script to work on that?
4. How can I access this value from resources manager?

I see "accessEndpoint" in path:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/**{subscriptionId}**/resourceGroups/**{resourceGroupName}**/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/**{logicAppName}**?api-version=2016-06-01

but once i use this value in my app settings i have access denied.

Callback URL from logic app site looks familiar to:
https://{server}.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/**{workflow}**/runs/**{someid}**/contents/TriggerInputs?api-version=2016-06-01&se=2017-10-30T13%3A34%3A27.3219438Z&sp=%2Fruns%2**someid2**%2Fcontents%2FTriggerInputs%2Fread&sv=1.0&sig=**{someid3}**

Comment: As far as I know, you could using powershell get call back url [method](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-powershell/blob/master/azureps-cmdlets-docs/ResourceManager/AzureRM.LogicApp/v2.1.0/Get-AzureRmLogicAppTriggerCallbackUrl.md) or [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/integrationaccounts/getcallbackurl) to get the call back url.

Comment: Brando Zhang, your solution is OK for me and works well :) Thanks, dude!

Answer (score 17):

Since you were asking about how to do it in ARM, here is the solution which assumes the LA has a trigger named **manual**:

```
listCallbackUrl(resourceId('resource-group-name','Microsoft.Logic/workflows', 'logic-app-name', 'manual'), '2016-06-01').value
```

If you're deploying the logic app and function app to the same resource group you can exclude the resource group name.

Here is how you might add the callback Url to your function settings:

```
{ 
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "kind": "functionapp",
  "name": "[variables('function_app_name')]",
  "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "identity": { "type": "SystemAssigned" },
  "properties": {
    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('function_hosting_plan_name'))]",
    "siteConfig":
    {
      "alwaysOn": true,
      "appSettings": [
        {
          "name": "Logic_App_Url",
          "value": "[listCallbackUrl(resourceId('resource-group-name','Microsoft.Logic/workflows/triggers', 'logic-app-name', 'manual'), '2016-06-01').value]"
        }
      ]
    },
    "resources": [
      {
        "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
        "name": "appsettings",
        "type": "config",
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storage_account_name'))]",
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('function_app_name'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "Logic_App_Url": "[listCallbackUrl(resourceId('resource-group-name','Microsoft.Logic/workflows/triggers', 'logic-app-name', 'manual'), '2016-06-01').value]"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Just so you are aware, your two examples here have inconsistent systax for the `resourceId` function parameter

Comment: Been a while since I wrote this answer, but [resourceId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#resourceid) has many optional params which aren't required, say, if the resource is 'nearby'

Comment: I was referring more to whether you have included `triggers` or not

Comment: Wonderful, I was looking to get it in a terrafrom arm template deployment.